# Are mini/pocket oscilloscopes like the DSO138 actually useful?

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm a beginner in electronics and I was searching for a cheap oscilloscope when I found out about those mini oscilloscopes that are really cheap. I wonder whether they actually have any serious use beyond just educational value.

Comment: It depends what you expect them to do and what you use them for. We can't know if it is useful or not for your purposes.

Comment: I haven't tried one of these, but the YouTube video [How good can a new $60 oscilloscope actually be?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ts5J09Y7Gc) might be of interest to you (the author finds better software in a later video). Regarding the DSO138, if you get it in kit form then at least you will have had the enjoyment of building it even if it doesn't end up being used, IMHO.

Comment: Like with any tool, read and understand the specs and see if they meet the requirements for your applications.

Comment: Better than nothing, at about $25 for a kit. The fact it runs on 12V was useful debugging something on my boat where AC mains was unavailable, and it was perfectly good for tracing 12V hall sensor pulses. The $200ish Hantek scopes are a vast step up though.

Comment: At the low price range I would get a USB scope to be honest and I hate USB scopes.. You get more functionality. The draw of a physical scope is physical knobs so all controls are immediately available but the DSO138 doesn't really have that so there's no point to it being physical. You probably want 2 channels almost immediately anyways.

Comment: I also recommend looking for used scopes, they might be just a bit more expensive and certainly more useful.

Comment: I have a single channel 20MSPS / 5 MHz bandwidth pocket scope with a built-in LiIon battery that's pretty useful to me. Initial cost was around €60 I believe. I bought it for my boat but I'm using it everywhere. It cannot do the deep analysis that my desk-based scope is capable of, but in the field I found it to be useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

I bought one something like 2 or 3 years ago.

What is nice is :

1. it is really cheap
2. you don't need to plug it to the mains (you can either use a 9 or 12V main adapter, a 9V battery, a 3S Lipo, ...). NB : the connector (at least on the version I got) is the same as the round power connector of an Arduino Uno. For my part, I usually power it either with a Lipo 3S, or with the charger of my Lipo (basically just a 12.6V power supply) if I want it on mains
3. it is very compact

On the other hand, there are several cons :

4. For me the worst : it has only a single channel : so you can't use it to observe relation between 2 signals (for example delays). NB : in case of digital signals, there is a trick : you connect a voltage divider between the 2 signals (with different values for the resistors), and measure the voltage at the middle point : depending on the voltage you know which signal is high or low
5. as already mentioned the bandwidth is limited to 200kHz, which is very low. Don't forget that excepted for a pure sine, you get deformation even at frequency far bellow the limit, because the harmonics (which exceed the limit) get lost. For example, don't hope to look a square waves above 20kHz (and even then, it's still quite distorted). Also, forget about looking at communication protocols (I2C, SPI, ...)
6. excepted for vertical scale and coupling, you don't have direct buttons for the other functions, so you have to cycle through the different parameters (trigger, horizontal scale, trigger type, vertical and horizontal offset) to change anything else, which is a bit time consuming

A bit less than a year after, I bought in addition a second hand USB scope : the one I got was quite unhandy, so whenever I could, I still used the DSO138, when needing the second channel of more bandwidth, I used the USB scope. I finally ended up buying second hand a 4 channel "classical" scope a few weeks ago.

So I would say :

- if you are really begging electronics, and you are not sure you want to continue, then I would recommend it (low cost). If you continue, expect to buy a "real" oscilloscope (classical with button or USB) later one, but the DSO138 can still be the fastest solution sometime for very simple tasks (specially if you buy a USB one as second one).
- if you want to do more serious electronics, then go directly for a real oscilloscope as you will soon need it anyway. Classical ones with buttons are far nicer to use, but USB ones are far cheaper for similar characteristics : so it's up to you. If you buy it second hand, I would rather reccomand to avoid the old analog scopes (those with green signal) as they are far more complicated to use and have usually far less functionalities (it is only a valid option if you are on very limited budget with a lot of time to loose)

Comment: Most folks consider analog scopes to be easier to use.  No menus, all the controls obviously and physically present on the front panel.

Comment: @jre Whichever one you encounter first is easier to use. Heh.

Comment: Well, I always prefered the digital ones, but if indeed you think that analog ones are better to begin with, then it might also be a good option, as you can get those quite cheap second hand (fo France, I found some in the 40-50€ range).
On the pros for the digital onces, I would say : 1) a color for each channel (ie no wondering what bellongs to which signal) 2) easy measurements (usual measurement like min/max/frequency/duty-cycle can be done automaticly instead of trying to mesure them with the cursors) 3) scales are usualy writtent on the screen 4) auto-trigger mode

Answer (score 2):

These are very inexpensive and have the following analog specification:

Analog bandwidth: 0 – 200KHz

If you are dealing with signals below this, say audio and the like, then this could be a very useful tool.  Perhaps even useful with some microcontroller (i.e. Arduino) or robotics projects.

If that's all you can afford, then it's probably better than nothing.